# Find text and handle values to PHP variables

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, substr

I have hard nut. I have this text in PHP variable, wich is from SSH's executed command, and I want to extract text to variables.

So, this is example text:

```
  Huawei Integrated Access Software (MA5683T).
  Copyright(C) Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 2002-2013. All rights reserved.

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  User last login information:
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Access Type : SSH 
  IP-Address  : 0.0.0.0 ssh
  Login  Time : 07.02.2017 20:01:48+01:00
  Logout Time : 07.02.2017 20:01:59+01:00
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

MA5683T>enable

MA5683T#display ont autofind all
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Number              : 1
   F/S/P               : 0/4/0
   Ont SN              : 48575443E1EAC883 (HWTC-E1EAC883)
   Password            : 0x00000000000000000000
   Loid                : 
   Checkcode           : 
   VendorID            : HWTC
   Ont Version         : 635.A
   Ont SoftwareVersion : V3R015C10S106
   Ont EquipmentID     : 010H
   Ont autofind time   : 06.02.2017 11:35:08+01:00
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Number              : 2
   F/S/P               : 0/4/0
   Ont SN              : 48575443ED9B1582 (HWTC-ED9B1582)
   Password            : 0x00000000000000000000
   Loid                : 
   Checkcode           : 
   VendorID            : HWTC
   Ont Version         : 635.A
   Ont SoftwareVersion : V3R015C10S106
   Ont EquipmentID     : 010H
   Ont autofind time   : 07.02.2017 15:57:35+01:00
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Number              : 3
   F/S/P               : 0/4/1
   Ont SN              : 48575443E1DA5683 (HWTC-E1DA5683)
   Password            : 0x00000000000000000000
   Loid                : 
   Checkcode           : 
   VendorID            : HWTC
   Ont Version         : 635.A
   Ont SoftwareVersion : V3R015C10S106
   Ont EquipmentID     : 010H
   Ont autofind time   : 07.02.2017 09:20:57+01:00
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   The number of GPON autofind ONT is 3

MA5683T#
```

I need to extract "Ont SN" (for example 48575443E1EAC883) and "F", "S" and "P" values (F/S/P : 0/4/0 in text).

Output will be:

```
$serial = "48575443E1EAC883"
$f = 0
$s = 4
$p = 0
```

Because there are 3 records, divided by ------ lines, i need to put in array.

Thank you for advice.

Comment: Text extraction is pretty easy but it would be easier with the original string and not the string we see here.

Comment: The serial is hex or alphanumeric? I think `F/S/P\h+:\h+(?<f>\d+)/(?<s>\d+)/(?<p>\d+)\s*Ont\h+SN\h+:\h+(?<serial>[A-F\d]+)` would do it, you then can check the index of the matches to see what it is. (Also don't use `/` delimiter with this regex or you'll need escaping.) https://regex101.com/r/ZUj8Jh/1

Comment: The serial is HEX. I don't have anything so far. My target is to make it tonight.

Comment: So the provided regex works?

Comment: Yes, but currently, I have only one record from SSH command, so output have SN triple times: 

Array ( [0] => F/S/P : 0/4/0 Ont SN : 48575443E1EAC883 [f] => 0 [1] => 0 [s] => 4 [2] => 4 [p] => 0 [3] => 0 [serial] => 48575443E1EAC883 [4] => 48575443E1EAC883 )

Comment: You mean you have everything twice, or in the provided input only 1 match should occur?

Comment: At this time, I have only one record in my device (instead of example at top of this page). I must work with this tonight. Look at this text: https://regex101.com/r/bR7snD/1 I have This output: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => F/S/P : 0/4/0 Ont SN : 48575443E1EAC883 ) [f] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [s] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [p] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [serial] => Array ( [0] => 48575443E1EAC883 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 48575443E1EAC883 ) )` I'm dummy for arrays, regex etc. Please help me to paste output to table. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching **Ont SN**:

```
/Ont SN\s*:\s*([\w]+)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/Q7zuk1/1

---

For matching **F/S/P**:

```
/F\/S\/P\s*:\s*(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/Q7zuk1/2

Comment: OK, but I need to grab it to array, because output must be printed as table with lines. Columns is SN, F, S, P.